# build error while pointing to variable in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using an xslt to transform an input xml in my springboot camel route based microservice. In the xsl i have to transform a date in the date-time format (eg: 2017-11-15T07:59:59.000Z) to MM/DD/YYYY format. I declared a variable in the xslt that maps the required date variable from the input xml as below and then transform the date as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="inputdate" select="root/parenttag/childtag/date"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
                  substring($inputdate, 9, 2),
                  '/',
                  substring($inputdate, 6, 2),
                  '/',
                  substring($inputdate, 1, 4)
                  )"/>
```

but when i build (using gradle) by application it throws as error in processResources task which is as below:

Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

> Could not copy file 'H:\git\applicationname\src\main\resources\xslt\Transform.xsl' to 'H:\git\applicationname\build\resources\main\xslt\Transform.xsl'.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with XSLT.  Maven is telling you it could not copy a file.  When posting error messages, please use `code block` formatting, and include ALL the messages.  The details are in the messages you omitted.

Comment: Just to add (and nothing related to the error), the XSLT code is not converting the date to `MM/DD/YYYY` format but it is converting it to `DD/MM/YYYY`. You may want to take a look into it.

Comment: @AniketV thanks..did correct that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got a solution to this one. So the task of compiling the xslt was in the  gradle task processResources. We excluded the xslt processing from there and it worked.

Added the following script in processResouces task

```
processResources {
filesNotMatching("**/*.xsl") {
    expand(project.properties)
}
dependsOn versionInfo
```

}

Note the fileNotMatching("**/*.xsl")

So anything that matches that file extension will not be processed under the task.